# jQuery pass argument to animate complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have few `<div>`'s which are dynamic. On click of these `<div>`'s, I want to trigger jQuery ui `switchClass` method which will change the class of another element from `col-sm-12` to `col-sm-9`.

Please find the code below:

HTML

```
 <div class="target" data-id="1">Item 1</div>
 <div class="target" data-id="2">Item 2</div>
 <div class="target" data-id="3">Item 3</div>
 <div class="target" data-id="4">Item 4</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.target').click(function(){

    $('#itemList').switchClass( "col-sm-12", "col-sm-9", 800, slideItems);

     function slideItems(){
      //I WANT TO GET DATA-ID here, exactly here
     }
});
```

Once the classes are switched, I want to execute `slideItems` function and access the clicked element's `data-id` inside it. for example `slideItems($this)`, I am not sure how to pass this currently clicked item to my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to change the context of callback function. Inside the callback, you can use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data) method to retrieve the data attribute.:

```
 $(document).on("click", '.target', function() {
  $('#itemList').switchClass("col-sm-12", "col-sm-9", 800, slideItems.bind(this));
});

function slideItems() {
  var elmId = $(this).data("id");
  alert(elmId);
}
```

```js
$(document).on("click", '.target', function() {
  $('#itemList').switchClass("col-sm-12", "col-sm-9", 800, slideItems.bind(this));
});

function slideItems() {
  var elmId = $(this).data("id");
  alert(elmId);
}
```

```css
target {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="target" data-id="1">Item 1</div>
<div class="target" data-id="2">Item 2</div>
<div class="target" data-id="3">Item 3</div>
<div class="target" data-id="4">Item 4</div>
<div id="itemList"></div>
```

If you want to keep the original context inside the callback, you can pass the clicked element as an argument to the callback as shown below:

```js
$(document).on("click", '.target', function() {
  var itemList = $('#itemList').get(0);
  $(itemList).switchClass("col-sm-12", "col-sm-9", 800, slideItems.bind(itemList, this));
});

function slideItems(target) {
  // this refers to #itemList
  var elmId = $(target).data("id");
  alert(elmId);
}
```

```css
target {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="target" data-id="1">Item 1</div>
<div class="target" data-id="2">Item 2</div>
<div class="target" data-id="3">Item 3</div>
<div class="target" data-id="4">Item 4</div>
<div id="itemList"></div>
```

Comment: WOW, this is working :) never knew bind can do such magic :D THANK TJ

Comment: @SyedSajid You might want to keep the original context to `#itemList` so that you can access it via `this`, So I updated the ans...

Comment: Sorry, this solution is wrong. OP wanted: "Once the classes are switched, I want to execute slideItems". There is a massive difference between "function" and "function()". You have to supply a function reference so the first is correct. If you put a "function()" as the parameter, it is a function call not reference. The function() is called first and its output is supplied to the parent function, which is called then (later). Result: slideItems.bindthe() will be executed first, then $(itemList).switchClass, last comes 800 ms delay (useless now). Think of a(b()), which one will be called first?

Comment: @Dave I don't think you understand what `bind` does

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the element itself with `$(this)`.

In my example, the code would work like this:

```
$(".target").click(function() {
    var target = $(this);
    $('#itemList').switchClass( "col-sm-12", "col-sm-9", 800, "linear", function(){ 
        slideItems( target ); 
    });
});

function slideItems($element){
  var elementtoslide = $element;
  elementtoslide.slideUp();  
}
```

**[SEE A FIDDLE OF THIS CODE IN ACTION HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wduzhb2d/1/)**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks good, I am using the TJ solution but this one is a smart way of doing it too... Thanks @radiovisual

Comment: This does not work properly. Function reference should be passed, not a return value from a function call. Read complete explanation in my comment un the T J's answer.